# Is 'Messi' Now a Recognized Word in Dictionaries?

Tags: nouns, dictionaries

I recently came across information stating that Lionel Messi's name has been incorporated into the Spanish dictionary as 'inmessionante.' This made me curious about how names and nouns related to popular figures are added to dictionaries.

Specifically, I'm interested in knowing whether 'Messi' is now officially recognized in dictionaries and what the process is for adding such nouns related to public figures.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a Spanish neologism which has nothing to do with either English dictionaries or learning English in general

Comment: @FF I agree.  Iman, you seem to have a misconception about dictionaries.  The only "process" is that the people who write dictionaries add the word.  Some dictionaries include lots of proper nouns,  many don't. It is a matter of judgement for the person writing the dictionary, and nothing more than that.  There is no "approval process" or "Standards committee" to decide words in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you quote doesn't say that the word *Messi* has been added to the dictionary, but that a new adjective with the footballer's name in it, *inmessionante*, has.

Newly invented words get into the dictionary when enough people start using a word for it to be regarded as part of the language. This applies whether the word relates to a public figure or not.